# Solving non-square linear equations with infinite number of solutions using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java

I am looking for a linear equation solver with infinite solutions. I want to output only one solution that satisfy the linear equation. After a long search I found the Apache Commons Math library and read it's manual. There isn't much explanation about how to use it. In my case, I have more variables than equations, so I tried to use SingularValueDecomposition as follows:

```
RealMatrix coefficients =
            new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] { { 1,2,2,3 }, { 2,4,1,3 }, { 3,6,1,4 } },
                               false);
        DecompositionSolver solver = new SingularValueDecomposition(coefficients).getSolver();
        RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 0,0,0 }, false);
        RealVector solution = solver.solve(constants);
```

But the output vector (solution) is { 0, 0, 0 }. I know it's a solution, but I want a solution that is not the zero vector. Is there any other method in this library that I can use to get another solution? Am I using it wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `solve` method returns `a vector X that minimizes the two norm of A × X - B`. Clearly this is not the way to get multiple solutions.

Comment: I would recomend you use ApacheMath's QR decomposition such that A=QR, where Q is Invertable (by itself) and R is an upper triangle Matrix. Then you can directly calculate a basis for the Kernel of R (which is a basis for the kernel of A as well).

Comment: See [*3.4 Solving linear systems*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html#a3.4_Solving_linear_systems) regarding QR or SVD.